# Change date output from "DD.MM.YYYY" to "DD/MM/YYYY" in <input type=date> tag

Tags: php, html

So basically somehow `<input type="date">` has format input "DD.MM.YYYY", but I need to have it with "/" - so "DD/MM/YYYY".

Comment: The value of a date input should be different between browsers because I am getting `YYYY-MM-DD` with Chrome.

Comment: Well when I looked down in the code for conditions I found one that is connected to the search thing. It says "if ((strlen($query) != 10) || (substr($query, 2, 1) != "/") || (substr($query, 5, 1) != "/")). I tried changing the "/" to "-", but it had no effect on the date input format.

Comment: What do you mean by "Date Input Format"? If you mean how the input control behaves in the browser, this is highly dependent on the browser used and the regional settings of the operating system the browser runs on.

Comment: I used Chrome and Firefox to view the program, but it was the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: I just want to change the / to period, that is all.

Comment: Can you please add the code you did in your first post?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change web-kit browsers use user's computer or mobiles default date format. But if you can use jquery and jquery UI there is a date-picker which is designable and can be shown in any format as the developer wants. the link to the jquery UI date-picker is on this page http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ you can find demo as well as code and documentation or documentation link

Answer (score 0):

So I searched on the internet and you can't change `-` to `/` in the input type date.
So it has to be text but and it will look like this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fbmakv60/)

```html
<input name=x size=10 maxlength=10  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'')" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replace` and a regular expression with the `g` flag to replace all ocurrences of `.`:

```js
const date = '15.05.2019';

console.log(
  date.replace(/\./g, '-')
);
```